# action script to add a pause button on a few audio buttons

Tags: actionscript-3

I am currently using the following code to play audio recordings from the project library.

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var sound1:Sound = new audio1();
var sound2:Sound = new audio2();

var mySoundChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

function stopSound():void
{
   //This stops all sound in the sound channel. 
   //If there is nothing playing, nothing happens.
   mySoundChannel.stop();
}

//In this function, we create an argument that allows us to tell the function 
//what sound to we want it to play.
function playSound(soundname:String):void
{
   try
   {
      mySoundChannel = this[soundname].play(0, 0);
   }
   catch(error:ReferenceError)
   {
      trace("playSound: That sound name doesn't exist.");
      return;
   }
 }

//Hook up buttons-->
button1.buttonMode = true;
button1.useHandCursor = true;

button2.buttonMode = true;
button2.useHandCursor = true;

button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button1click);
button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button2click);

function button1click(evt:Event):void
{
   stopSound();
   playSound("sound1");
}

function button2click(evt:Event):void
{
   stopSound();
   playSound("sound2");
}
```

I need to pause the currently playing audio when a button is clicked. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do five things to your current code in order to pause and resume the currently playing sound:

1. Create a variable that stores the name of the currently playing
   sound, and a variable to store the pause position of the audio.
2. Create a pause function.
3. Create a resume function.
4. Expand the current playSound and stopSound functions to work with the new variables.
5. Hook up the button event listener.

**Step 1:**

```
var currentSound:String = "";
var pausePosition:Number = 0;
```

**Step 2:** We're going to save the current position of the audio in that second variable we just created. We can get the current play position of the audio using the [mySoundChannel.position](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html#position) property, which returns a Number value (matching the Number type we gave the pausePosition variable).

```
function pauseSound():void
{
   //If there's a song to pause...
   if(currentSound != "")
   {
      //Get pause position.
      pausePosition = mySoundChannel.position;
      //Stop the sound directly.
      mySoundChannel.stop();
   }
}
```

Note we didn't call stopSound(). There's a good reason for that. We're going to put an extra line of code in that function shortly that we don't want to use in pauseSound().

**Step 3:** Now we create the function to resume audio. Note this is NOT the same as playSound(). We're telling it to start playing from pausePosition, not from 0 (the beginning of the sound clip).

```
function resumeSound():void
{
   //If there's a song to resume...
   if(currentSound != "")
   {
      //Start playing the current audio from the position we left off at.
      mySoundChannel = this[currentSound].play(pausePosition);
   }
}
```

**Step 4:** Since we're now working with those variables we declared in step 1, we need to adjust how playSound() and stopSound() work.

In playSound(), instead of just passing soundname to the sound channel, we're going to save the soundname to currentSound.

```
function playSound(soundname:String):void
{
   try
   {
      currentSound = soundname
      mySoundChannel = this[currentSound].play(0, 0);
   }
   catch(error:ReferenceError)
   {
      trace("playSound: That sound name doesn't exist.");
      return;
   }
}
```

In stopSound(), we need to actually clear the currentSound and pausePosition variables when we stop, to ensure that resumeSound doesn't start audio after we've totally stopped it.

```
function stopSound():void
{
   //This stops all sound in the sound channel. 
   //If there is nothing playing, nothing happens.
   mySoundChannel.stop();

   //Clear our variables.
   currentSound = "";
   pausePosition = 0;
}
```

**GOTCHA WARNING:** Ordinarily, you can loop audio by passing an integer other than 0 in the second argument (where I have the 5) in the following code:

```
mySoundChannel = this[currentSound].play(0, 5);
```

In the above code, the sound would play from the beginning, and repeat five times.

However, if you are starting the audio from any position other than 0, what will actually happen is that the audio will loop at the position you start at, not at the beginning.

That is to say, if you use this code:

```
mySoundChannel = this[currentSound].play(1000, 5);
```

The sound will loop five times, but every time the sound starts over in the loop, it will start playing from position 1000, and NOT the beginning of the sound (0).

I hope that answers your question!